# Which is right timing to get URL

Tags: reactjs

I want to get a key from server at page initial and use this key to get data in other component.

```
var Page = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        var key = this.getKey();
        return { key: key };
    },   
    getKey: function () {
        var key;
        $.ajax({
            url: Api.GetMasterkey,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                urlParamter:''
            },
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                key = data;
            }.bind(this),
        });

        return key;
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
             <div>
                <ContentA key={this.key} />
                <ContentB key={this.key} />                
             </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Page;
```

The key's value depends on urlPagramter. I try to parse url in getKey function but I find the url shows timing is after getInitialState.

So, which timing is right to get url pagramter? If my design is wrong please feel free to correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*First off, this is slightly off topic, but bear with me: Don't call your prop `key` in ContentA and ContentB. It is a reserved prop name for the inner mechanics of React to generate a react-id, and unless that's the purpose, call it something else. Besides, referring to `this.key` makes no sense. It would be `this.state.key`*

By definition the Ajax operation i async, so `key` will always be undefined when it is returned from `getKey`. If you really must have `key` before the page is rendered for the first time, then you have to do your API call before rendering anything with React. Imagine you have an index.js or some other point of entry for you app, this is usually the same place where you call ReactDOM.render(). In this top level file, do the API call

```
$.ajax({
        url: Api.GetMasterkey,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            urlParamter:''
        },
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            /* This function is executed when data is received. Run ReactDOM.render from here, and pass data as a prop. */
        }
    });
```

In Page, now it is simply a matter of setting the inital state using the passed prop.

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    key: this.props.data // or whatever you call your prop
  };
}
```

A different approach, if `ContentA` and `ContentB` can handle being without a key for a moment, is doing the Ajax call in Page's `componentDidMount` function, and call `setState` when the success function is called in the ajax function.

```
var Page = React.createClass({
  ...
  ...
  componentDidMount(){
    // Do Ajax stuff after the component has mounted
    var that = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: Api.GetMasterkey,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            urlParamter:''
        },
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            // Change state after the data has been received.
            that.setState({
                key: data
            });
        }
    });
  }
  ...
  ...
  ...
})
```

Now the render function will trigger again as soon as the reply from the Api is ready, and ComponentA and ComponentB can make use of the key by referring to `this.state.key`.

Comment: My mistake, the timing I get url is right the problem is in the other function. The code in my question is just for sample and I forgot the `key` is keyword. My problem is solved now, Your advise is very good and I will put my code tomorrow, maybe we can discuss more. Thank you.

Comment: BTW, I call the API in my first component not in the top level file. ContentA will call the other API with key so I want to initial key at first. I can handle ContentA without key by adding some code in it. I do not know what kind of design is better.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's why I said that one solution is to call the API before any React stuff is going on. The way you implement it now, the initial render will _always_ happen before you get any results from the API, because Ajax is async. Javascript doesn't stop execution while waiting for a request to be done.

Comment: Even I use  `async: false,` and write it in  `getInitialState`?

Comment: The `async` setting is deprecated, and your logic should be handled in the success callback. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: OMG, I don't know it's deprecated...I will check my code tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Page = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        var masterKey = this.loadMasterKey();
        return { masterKey: masterKey };
    },
    getURLParameter: function (name) {        
        return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search) || [, ""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20')) || null;
    },
    loadMasterKey: function () {
        var masterKey;
        $.ajax({
            url: Api.GetMasterkey,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                id: this.getURLParameter('id'),
            },
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                masterKey = data.SuccessPayLoad;
            }.bind(this),
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(xhr, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });

        return masterKey;
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
             <div>
                <Header />
                <Content masterKey={this.state.masterKey} />                 
                <Footer />
             </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Page;
```

This is my code now and page is root component.

You can see in the function getInitialState the data which I will send to server is get from url(the getInitialState function) and I set the async to false.

I will pass the masterKey to child component like Content and Content will use this masterKey to get data from server async.

I do not write any code in Content to handle exception before key return. The program is working good now **but I should handle it**.